# JQuery function based on string length misfiring

Tags: jquery, input

The following function should reveal a panel when the input has 3 or more characters inside it and is not equal to the placeholder.

```
$('#search').keydown(function(){
            $('#header .suggestion').removeClass('visible');
            var slength = $(this).val();
            if(slength.length > 2 && slength != $(this).attr('placeholder')){
                //activate AJAX script
                $('#header .results').addClass('visible');
            }
            else {
                $('#header .results').removeClass('visible');
            }

    });
```

Instead it doesn't appear until 5 characters are displayed. Why.

Marvellous

Comment: Can you make a fiddle please ? www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RussC I haven't got time just now but I'll get to it later

Comment: some more code might be helpful. at first look, this part `slength != $(this).attr('placeholder')` might be causing the problem.

Comment: what is 'placeholder' ? try some debug, take out the != and try only with length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `keydown` and `keypress` events are called BEFORE the browser has processed the input. During these events, the developer can add a method to prevent the user from entering text.

So, when you're listening to the `keydown` function, the `$(this).val()` does NOT return the "expected" value.

An image (the user has already focused on the input field):

```
{ } <-- Empty input field
    [X] <-- Use presses the X key
    **KEYDOWN**
    **KEYPRESS**
{X} <-- "x" appears in the text field
    **KEYUP**
```

To get the "expected" value of the input, you have to use the `keyup` event instead of `keydown`.